# MongoDB ORM for Python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to migrate from sqlalchemy(SQlite) to using mongodb.  I would like schema vertification.  I amm looking at mongokit, but I want something which is similar to mappers, so that it would save from the object's property, and not a dict.

i would like a mapper so that i can use existing objects without modifying them.

Comment: Precisely, it should be called "DRM" (Document-Resource-Mapping)

Comment: This should help you answer your query http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php-libraries/

Comment: There's a library called mongolia that let's you interact with mongo objects via attributes or dictionary access and has schema verification that you can enable: https://github.com/zagaran/mongolia

Comment: @zsong Relational and Document... Shouldnt be called Object Relational and Object Document?

Comment: this may be helpful: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-MongoAlchemy/

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Another option is [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/). The ORM for MongoEngine is very similar to the ORM used by Django.

Example (from the tutorial):

```
class Post(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    author = ReferenceField(User)

class TextPost(Post):
    content = StringField()

class ImagePost(Post):
    image_path = StringField()

class LinkPost(Post):
    link_url = StringField()
```

Comment: AFAIK. You can't add properties on the fly to mongoengine's Document. Which kind of takes some fun away from mongodb.

Comment: You can use the DictField to add any kind of totally schemaless data if you need to.

Comment: Or the GenericEmbeddedDocument?

Comment: Mongoengine has some serious performance issues. If you want to use it in production, it will only work if you have a very simple, lightweight schema.

Comment: @ValerieR.Coffman do you have references for this performance claim?

Comment: You can use the Django ORM directly with Mongodb instead of using Mongoengine by using the [djongo connection](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/)

Comment: For those looking for a more comprehensive overview of MongoDB ORMs available for Python, the PyMongo "Tools" page lists quite a few of them, and is regularly maintained: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tools.html

Comment: Take a look at pymongoext https://github.com/musyoka-morris/pymongoext which is inspired by mongoose

Comment: @axd https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1230

Comment: The PyMongo tools page has moved: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tools.html

Answer (score 42):

Not being satisfied with either MongoKit or MongoEngine, I decided to write my own object-oriented interface for Python.

I delegated all queries directly to pymongo, so the query syntax there is the same.  Mostly, it's just an object-wrapper around the results, with some other helpers like database connection pooling, DBRef support, and other convenience methods to make your life easier.

It's called [Minimongo](http://github.com/slacy/minimongo) and it's available from github.  Happy hacking!

Example:

```
from minimongo import Model, MongoCollection 

class MyObject(Model): 
    model = MongoCollection(database='test', collection='my_collection')

m = MyObject()
m.x = 1
m.field = 'value'
m.other = {'list': True}
m.save()

x = MyObject({'x': 1, 'y': 2}).save()

objs = MyObject.find({'x': 1})
for o in objs: 
    print o
```

Comment: This is super useful and simple, I just wanted something so that I am not stuck creating dictionaries, nothing else.

Comment: This is really nice. Too bad its not maintained anymore :(

Answer (score 31):

You want [MongoKit](https://github.com/namlook/mongokit). It is one layer of abstraction higher than [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.6/index.html). Not sure if you're using Django, but there's also [django-mongokit](http://github.com/peterbe/django-mongokit) integration.

Example from this [blog post](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-and-why-to-use-django-mongokit). Note that instances of Computer can then reference make/model directly once the structure is defined ( e.g. atari.make, c64.model, ... ). No need for dictionaries:

```
import datetime 
from mongokit import Document

class Computer(Document):

    structure = { 
      'make': unicode, 
      'model': unicode, 
      'purchase_date': datetime.datetime, 
      'cpu_ghz': float, 
    }

    validators = { 
      'cpu_ghz': lambda x: x > 0, 
      'make': lambda x: x.strip(), 
    }

    default_values = { 
      'purchase_date': datetime.datetime.utcnow, 
    }

    use_dot_notation = True

    indexes = [ 
      {'fields': ['make']}, 
    ]
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without modifying existing business logic objects?  in sqlalchemy, you can use mappers.

Comment: more surgical change. keeps your dependency graph clean. makes sense, though I don't see a way to do this directly. Maybe something strange like class MongoComputer(Computer,Document) or with some form of mix in? Interesting...

Comment: its clean in sqlalchemy, thus the question, thans

Comment: No code changes in mongokit since 2015 and no release since 2014. damn, I don't get this python world :( .

Comment: MongoKit is dead

Answer (score 17):

I know I'm really late to this question, but I'm the author of Ming http://merciless.sourceforge.net, a SQLAlchemy-inspired MongoDB validation and ORM engine. It's what we use at SourceForge, and there's a reasonable presentation available at http://www.slideshare.net/rick446/rapid-and-scalable-development-with-mongodb-pymongo-and-ming as well as a case study on migrating from SQLAlchemy to Ming http://www.slideshare.net/__amol__/from-sqlalchemy-to-ming-with-turbogears2. Here's an example of the ORM layer in Ming (from the tutorial):

```py
class WikiPage(MappedClass):

    class __mongometa__:
        session = session
        name = 'wiki_page'

    _id = FieldProperty(schema.ObjectId)
    title = FieldProperty(str)
    text = FieldProperty(str)
    comments=RelationProperty('WikiComment')
```

Queries use the standard MongoDB query syntax (not Django ORM's magic keyword arguments):

```py
WikiComment.query.find(dict(page_id=wp._id))
```

Comment: Ming seems for us the way to go. It has both the flexibility and the schema-ish concepts we need. When we need power we drop down to pymongo.

Comment: I am new to mongo and python. Is there a tutorial where I can refer to for creating Models like django's model.py and create migration scripts using Ming.