# Python Web Framework with best Mongo support

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm looking to write a small web app to utilise a dataset I already have stored in a MongoDB collection. I've been writing more Python than other languages lately and would like to broaden my repertoire and write a Python web app.

It seems however that most if not all of the current popular Python web development frameworks favour MySQL and others with no mention given to MongoDB.

I am aware that there are more than likely plugins written to allow Mongo be used with existing frameworks but so far have found little as to documentation that compares and contrasts them.

I was wondering what in people's experience is the Python web development framework with the best MongoDB support?

Many thanks in advance,

Patrick

Answer (score 11):

I have not tried MongoKit although it has been around for a while and retains a good reputation. I personally prefer [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org) and feel very comfortable with it (maybe because I like its nice homepage and good documentation). There is also a very good opensource project named [Mumblr](https://github.com/hmarr/django-mumblr) which demonstrates a Django-MongoEngine-MongoDB combination, which I think a very good starter for any project. I'm developing a CMS for my own company using this app.

Comment: MongoEngine looks to be very nice and user friendly. I'll definitely give it a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've used [MongoKit](https://github.com/namlook/mongokit) with Pylons before and it worked out good.

You might want to refer to this post though: [MongoDB ORM for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781682/mongodb-orm-for-python)

Answer (score 0):

There is no stable support for mongodb using django framework. I tried using mongoengine, but unlike models, provided for admin in django framework, there is no support for mongoengine.

Correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Flask is the best framework to use with MongoDB. It has a mongodb library called  [flask-pymongo](https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Make sure you run the following commands before starting your project.

```
$ pip3 install Flask
$ pip3 install Flask-PyMongo
```