# completely abstract data source for an object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I apologize in advance if this question is too general, or a solution exists that I haven't found via searching yet.

I was working on a simple REST server with web.py, and my backend was mysql, so I used sqlalchemy declarative objects. Everything works amazingly well, but I found myself tied pretty tightly to using a database that sqlalchemy supports at that time. If I wanted to switch to mongodb, or something else, my sqlalchemy-specific declarative classes would have to be rewritten or scrapped.

I was wondering if there was any project (or, more generally, an example of a design pattern) that allowed you to plug in any backend. I'm sure it would take a decent amount of coding to be able to switch from a sql backend to a mongo backend (for example), but if there were any well known strategies to minimize the pain, I'd be very curious to hear about them.

Thanks very much for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you select an ORM for MongoDB:

[MongoDB ORM for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781682/mongodb-orm-for-python)

I find it hard to believe that any transition from a relational to a NoSQL database under the hood of an ORM would work seamlessly for any non-trivial project. However, if you actually need to migrate at some point there are some ORMs that have similar semantics to SQLAlchemy (Ming looks promising but I've never used it yet).

You might want to take a look at the [StackOverflow architecture described on High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/10/24/stackexchange-architecture-updates-running-smoothly-amazon-4.html). In a nutshell, SQL databases can get you very far.

Also have a look at [The Case Against ORM Frameworks In High Scalability Architectures](http://highscalability.com/blog/2008/2/2/the-case-against-orm-frameworks-in-high-scalability-architec.html) and contemplate whether you want to use an ORM once you need to scale out.

One can also use both: An SQL database wherever you need transactions, a NoSQL database for logging, events, and other fields where NoSQL DBs are good at.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I guess my question is more: "Is there a known way to keep the model completely ignorant of where the data is coming from? Some sort of model-data interface pattern?" I think I might be over-thinking it, though, and SQL will be good enough to solve any problem I run into in the immediate future, especially in light of your last statement. Thanks again!