# How to test data before it gets stored in a database?

Tags: python

I'm writing a python module that will contain some functions that will manipulate a mongodb database.

How can I go about validating input data passed to that function before saving it in database?

For example, lets say one of the function in module is `createUser(user)` which accepts a python dictionary as argument. This dictionary contains user information to save in the database. I want to create an automated validation routine which checks that the dictionary structure matches the database structure.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with this, but I think you might want to use an ORM (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781682/mongodb-orm-for-python) - though you would lose the flexibility of a NoSQL DB.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware about the possibility of using an ORM but in this case I want to directly manipulate MongoDB database.

Comment: https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/cerberus/.  I like voluptuous but now prefer cerberus. All rules can be declared in a human readable yaml file as opposed to the need for callables in voluptuous and other libraries.

Comment: http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/   how about this

Answer (score 4):

I released "pyvaru" (https://github.com/daveoncode/pyvaru) a couple of days ago, it is a simple, flexible and unobtrusive data validation library for Python 3 (3.4+), based on the concept of validation rules.

Quote from the doc:

> Given an existing model to validate, like the one below (but it could
>   be a simple dictionary or any data structure since pyvaru does not
>   make any assumption on the data format):
>
> ```
> class User:
>     def __init__(self, first_name: str, last_name: str, date_of_birth: datetime, sex: str):
>         self.first_name = first_name
>         self.last_name = last_name
>         self.date_of_birth = date_of_birth
>         self.sex = sex
> ```
>
> We have to define a validator, by implementing the get_rules() method
>   and for each field we want to validate we have to provide one or more
>   proper rule(s).
>
> ```
> from pyvaru import Validator
> from pyvaru.rules import TypeRule, FullStringRule, ChoiceRule, PastDateRule
>
> class UserValidator(Validator):
>     def get_rules(self) -> list:
>         user = self.data # type: User
>         return [
>             TypeRule(apply_to=user,
>                      label='User',
>                      valid_type=User,
>                      error_message='User must be an instance of user model.',
>                      stop_if_invalid=True),
>             FullStringRule(user.first_name, 'First name'),
>             FullStringRule(user.last_name, 'Last name'),
>             ChoiceRule(user.sex, 'Sex', choices=('M', 'F')),
>             PastDateRule(user.date_of_birth, 'Date of birth')
>         ]
> ```
>
> Finally we have two choices regarding how to use our custom validator:
>
> As a context processor:
>
> ```
> with UserValidator(user):
>     # do whatever you want with your valid model
> ```
>
> In this case the code inside with will be executed only if the
>   validation succeed, otherwise a ValidationException (containing a
>   validation_result property with the appropriate report) is raised.
>
> By invoking the validate() method (which returns a ValidationResult)
>
> ```
> validation = UserValidator(user).validate()
> if validation.is_successful():
>     # do whatever you want with your valid model
> else:
>     # you can take a proper action and access validation.errors
>     # in order to provide a useful message to the application user,
>     # write logs or whatever
> ```
>
> Assuming we have a instance of an User configured as the one below:
>
> ```
> user = User(first_name=' ',
>             last_name=None,
>             date_of_birth=datetime(2020, 1, 1),
>             sex='unknown')
> ```
>
> By running a validation with the previous defined rules we will obtain
>   a ValidationResult with the following errors:
>
> ```
> {
>     'First name': ['String is empty.'],
>     'Last name': ['Not a string.'],
>     'Sex': ['Value not found in available choices.'],
>     'Date of birth': ['Not a past date.']
> }
> ```

Comment: Does pyvaru support conditional field validations?