# How to check the types contained in a list?

Tags: python, error-reporting

I want to do the following without defining a function:

```
if isinstance(x,(list,tuple)) and every_element_isinstance(x,basestring):
   foobar
```

ie: `implementing type checking`

Is there a shorthand/`builtin` for this?

Comment: Why don't you want to define a function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is the best solution (if I understand the question)

```
if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and all(isinstance(i, basestring) for i in x):
    #do whatever
```

Comment: This solution without any list comprehension `([... for ...])` is better espetially for slow conditions because the list comprehension evaluates all conditions even if the first one is not satisfied.

Comment: `isinstance(x, collections.Iterable)` might be more suitable here

Answer (score 5):

```
if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and all([isinstance(i, basestring) for i in x]):
    foobar
```

Surprisingly, a list comprehension with `[ ... ]` is faster here than one without, both with short and long lists:

short lists:

```
>>> timeit('isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and all(isinstance(i, basestring) for i in x)', "x=['a','b','c']")
2.7594685942680144
>>> timeit('isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and all(isinstance(i, basestring) for i in x)', "x=['a','b','c']")
2.8013695153947538
>>> timeit('isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and all([isinstance(i, basestring) for i in x])', "x=['a','b','c']")
2.4351678506033068
>>> timeit('isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and all([isinstance(i, basestring) for i in x])', "x=['a','b','c']")
2.4491469896721583
```

long lists:

```
>>> timeit('isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and all(isinstance(i, basestring) for i in x)', "x=['a','b','c'] * 1000", number=1000)
1.3357901657891489
>>> timeit('isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and all(isinstance(i, basestring) for i in x)', "x=['a','b','c'] * 1000", number=1000)
1.3305278872818462
>>> timeit('isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and all([isinstance(i, basestring) for i in x])', "x=['a','b','c'] * 1000", number=1000)
1.2626525921055531
>>> timeit('isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and all([isinstance(i, basestring) for i in x])', "x=['a','b','c'] * 1000", number=1000)
1.2881240045551863
```

Comment: @Volatility one second after I submitted my answer I saw yours popup. Great minds think alike I guess :D

Comment: which one should I aceept then ? I mean both are perfect

Comment: well, Volatility has less reputation so ..., sorry BrtH

Comment: Haha, thanks, I was just about to say my solution was better because it had two less characters :P

Comment: actually I should have chosen BrtH's since Volatility's has a typo

Comment: That's good reasoning of both of you, haha! But I have one upvote more, so at least I get some rep :P

Comment: @Volatility I decided to test which answer is better. Surprisingly, I win, although it isn't a significant difference.

Comment: And what if, like heynekcer said, the first element is not a string?

Comment: @Volatility good one, I did some additional tests: in that case it is almost exactly the other way around. For both small and long lists, if the first element is an int you win, if the last element is an int I win. If the non-string element is in the middle of the list, I win for short list and you win for long lists.

Comment: Which ultimately means my solution is better because it is shorter! :P

Answer (score 5):

There is not built-in to define [generic types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming). But there are [a lot of validation libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12235120/89391), which can mimic this functionality.

Example using https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous:

```
>>> from voluptuous import Schema
>>> s_list = Schema([basestring]) # only strings in a list are allowed
>>> s_list("hello") 
...
voluptuous.InvalidList: expected a list
>>> s_list([123])
...
voluptuous.InvalidList: invalid list value @ data[0]
>>> s_list(["correct"])
["correct"] # returns the object, if validation was successful
```

A few days ago, [support for tuple was added](https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous/commit/fb942615fab1f13c1af4f7bc71e8a7f538d32474) to this library:

```
>>> s_tuple = voluptuous.Schema((basestring, ))
```

Now combine the two to get your result:

```
>>> from voluptuous import any

# - this is now equivalent to your code
# - raises Exceptions on invalid input
>>> schema = Schema(any(s_list, s_tuple))
```

It's even slightly faster that the double-`isinstance`:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit

>>> timeit('(schema(i) for i in x)', "x=['a','b','c']")
0.679318904876709

>>> timeit("""
        (isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) 
         and all(isinstance(i, basestring)) for i in x)""", "x=['a','b','c']")
0.7801780700683594
```

Answer (score 0):

With voluptuous '0.8.7' you can update answer from [miku](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14181819/2944893) and skip the "tuple part":

```
>>> from voluptuous import Schema
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> s_list = Schema([basestring]) # only strings in a list are allowed
>>> timeit('(s_list(i) for i in x)', "x=['a','b','c']")
0.503572940826416
>>> timeit("(isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and all(isinstance(i, basestring)) for i in x)", "x=['a','b','c']")
0.5400209426879883
```