# How to validate csv data read by pandas.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Looking to validate the data in a csv file using Python and Pandas. Everything works fine when feeding clean data. However when there is a problem with the data, the issues are hard to find. Raising any sort of error would be great. Here is some pseudo code:

```
dtypes = {'Date': 'str', 'yesno': 'str', 'int_val': 'int', 'decimal_value': 'str'}
df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype=dtypes)

# Ensure exceptions are thrown for invalid data.

# valid date format in date. ValueError raised for invalid data.
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# 'yes' or 'no' for the yesno field. (has to be in a list of values)
# valid integer for int_val.
# a valid integer or decimal number for decimal_value
```

I am not even sure the pd.to_datetime is the best way to validate a date. What is a good way of doing this?

Comment: check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235120/simple-data-validation) he uses a data validation library for Python

Comment: What do you want to do once you find invalid data?

Comment: Raising any error is fine. The pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) statement raises a ValueError if there is an invalid date format anywhere.

Comment: Then, you have your answer.

Comment: Not really: How about the other items: Items that must be in a list of values, integers or decimal values? There might be a way of calling read_csv that will do all the work.  Doing the validation after the read could be quite inefficient.

Comment: The only possible source of errors are `int_val`, when loading, and `Date`, when attempting the cast. Nothing else could possibly throw an error - any invalid non-numeric data will remain a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'yes' or 'no' for the yesno field. (has to be in a list of values):

```
df.yesno.isin(['yes','no']).all() # Returns False if there are any other values
```

valid integer for int_val:

```
df.int_val.astype(int) # Throws an error if there are non-integers
# or, if int_val are floats:
import numpy as np
np.isclose(df.int_val.round(0),df.int_val.astype(int)).all()
```

a valid integer or decimal number for decimal_value:

```
df.decimal_value.astype(float) # similar to above
```

Using `pd.to_datetime()` to validate dates is probably best; you can also specify the format of the dates if necessary, e.g. with the keyword argument `format = '%y-%m-%d'` which expects dates to be of the form `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful.